# Cisco Switch triggers config trap on reboot

Tags: snmp

We have a cisco switch in our network that is configured to send config change traps on a specific host. But when the device reboots due to some physical issue, the device triggers the config traps. Can some body explain why the switch is triggering the config trap even when there is no config change.

Comment: What is switch model and version of software?

Comment: switch model is 2960 and version is Cisco IOS Software, C2960X Software (C2960X-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(2)EX5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch boots up into the default configuration. Then it loads the configuration saved in memory. That’s considered a change.

Comment: I think config change related to self-tests that performed by device

Comment: I also thought that because the switch loads the configuration from the memory that's why the config traps are triggered but normally the config traps are triggered when someone goes into "conf t" of the device and the device does not go to "conf t" while loading the configuration on start up so why the traps are being triggered?

Comment: Regardless of the ultimate "why," I'm unaware of a way to stop it.